# Force to reimplement a static function in inherit classes

Tags: c++

I have a program in C++ with plugins (dynamic libs). In the main program, I want to execute a static function to check if i can create a object of this type.

An example without dynamic libs (aren't neccesary to understand the problem):

```
#include "libs/parent.h"
#include "libs/one.h"
#include "libs/two.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Parent* obj;

    if (One::match(argv[1]))
        obj = new One();
    else if (Two::match(argv[1]))
        obj = new Two();
}
```

Now, i have a interface class named Parent. All plugins inherit from this class. Ideally, I have a virtual static function in Parent named match, and all the plugins need to reimplement this function.

The problem with this code is that i can't do a static virtual function in C++, so i don't know how to solve the problem.

Sorry for mi english, i did my best

Comment: If the `match()` function is static, wouldn't you be calling it as `One::match()`? Why does it have to be static?

Comment: Sorry, i corrected the mistake
It have to be static because i need to call it before creating the object

Comment: No worries, I think using a pure virtual method would work for you, but that isn't static. So perhaps others' answers may help you more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have here is classic **factory** pattern. You want to create an interface named `IPluginFactory` which would have two methods - `match` and `create` (or, optionally, combine them both in a single method). Then each of your plugin DLLs would have a class that implements this interface.

```
    Parent obj;
    IPluginFactory *one = new OneFactory();
    IPluginFactory *two = new TwoFactory();

    if (one->match(argv[1]))
        obj = one->createObj();
    else if (two->match(argv[1]))
        obj = two->createObj();
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address `virtual static` functions.

Comment: It does address the question, though.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to static functions. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: It solves the problem the poster has. It does not relate to static methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could add some `static string` to each of your plugins, that would hold it's name. Or make some struct called `PluginID` and add this `string` to this struct (and probably something else plugin-specific).

Now matching in runtime seems to become very simple. Just check whether that static identification string from your plugin matches your argv.

This is a commonly used implementation of a so-called "your-own-and-simple-rtti", guess it would solve your problems.

Comment: The `match` methods do not necessarily check for simple equality.

Comment: I do agree that creating an object factory would be a better solution, but my intuition actually says that this simple rtti-implementation is what would work in this particular case

Comment: The problem is that the match() method is more complicated than simple comparation of the string passed by argv, but thank you!